# initialize child class with parent

Tags: python, inheritance

Having a parent and a child class I would like to
initialize the child class with a parent instance.
My way seems very cumbersome (see below):

I define a staticmethod to extract `init` parameters for parent initialization:

```
class Parent(object):
    @staticmethod
    get_init_params(parent_obj):
        a = parent_obj.a
        b = parent_obj.b
        return (a, b)

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Parent, self).__init__(*get_init_params(parent))
```

Is there possibly a more direct way?

**EDIT** now the classes are simpler

Comment: Why are you doing the change and reversion in parent class? Why not just have instance variables for initial arguments (like old_a, old_b) and then keep the regular variables the same? That way you can just check parent.old_a, etc.

Comment: could do that but then i 'd have the same problem: I would need the `get_init_params` method to extract them from the old parent. The `get_init_params` method would just be slightly easier

Comment: This doesn't make sense as a way of organizing code. What are `change_{a,b}` even doing? Unless they're gross stateful functions, this control flow has you undoing a change in the parent constructor, just to redo it later... I guess that's what you want to improve.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you want to separate the notion of *intializing* a `Child` object from the notion of *creating* one from a `Parent`. The `get_init_params` is just adding a layer of complexity you don't need; access the attributes directly.

```
class Child(Parent):
    @classmethod
    def from_parent(cls, parent):
        return cls(parent.a, parent.b)

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super(Child, self).__init__(a, b)
        # Note: the fact that yo have to do this,
        # or not call the parent's __init__ in the first
        # place, makes me question whether inheritance
        # is the right tool here.
        self.a = revert_change(self.a)
        self.b = revert_change(self.b) 

p = Parent(3, 5)
c1 = Child.from_parent(p)
c2 = Child(6, 6)
```

If there are changes to make to the values you get from the parent, apply them in `to_parent` before creating the `Child` object.

```
def from_parent(cls, parent):
    return cls(revert_change(parent.a), revert_change(parent.b))
    # Or, if you save the original values
    # return cls(parent.orig_a, parent.orig_b)
```

Comment: This applies the changes in the constructor twice - once when initing the parent, once when passing its attributes to the overridden constructor for the child -- presumably breaking it. But that's why he should back behavior out of the init method.

Comment: Thanks, that is a way, but what would i do if i wanted to be able to put parent in the `__init__` method ? I mean to call the child directly `Child(parent)`

Comment: You don't. Leave `__init__` to initialize the `Child` *directly*, and use the alternate constructor that expects a `Parent`.

Comment: @jwilner Yeah, after I saw his edit, I decided to ignore the issue of making/reversing the changes to the arguments.

Comment: Oh, my bad, he moved the changing behavior out of the constructor. This is trivial now.

Comment: Okay, thanks, why don't I? I use the Child mostly as an Interface on the parent, (for example just to reinterpret the parent's fields) therefore there will never be another way to instantiate the child.

Comment: @ProfHase85 That sounds like `Child` should actually just be an alternate constructor for `Parent`, then, not a separate class.

Comment: @ProfHase85, the point isn't what will be the only path used for the child class, it's what will enable the most code reuse. A constructor shouldn't have behavior backed into it simply because it's going to be the main route to instantiating the object. This is exactly what class level methods are for...

Comment: @chepner : For example Parent class: `Table` with rows 1-10; Child1: `FoodTable` where `get_bananas` returns the second row and Child2: `StreetsTable` where `get_House` returns a comination of row1 and row2

It would make no sense to initialize any of the child classes with anything other then the table. So, is the design wrong?

Comment: No, but you want the `Parent` to be the lowest common denominator for *all* the children. If you are making changes in `Parent.__init__` that don't apply to *any* child, then those changes belong in another subclass of `Parent` that your child *doesn't* inherit from.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments in my original answer, I believe you don't want to subclass `Parent`; rather, you just want alternate constructors.

```
class Parent(object):

    # The basic initializer; just use whatever values are
    # passed directly to it
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @classmethod
    def type_1(cls, a, b):
        return cls(change_a1(a), change_b1(b))

    @classmethod
    def type_2(cls, a, b):
        return cls(change_a2(a), change_b2(b))

    # etc
```

If you really *do* want a subclass of `Parent`, then there's no need to back out any changes; `Parent` only includes functionality that applies to *all* children.

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super(Child, self).__init__(a, b)
        # Any Child-specific initialization
```

Comment: Based on his comments on your other answer: he should stop rolling his own database! :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not save the init parameters and create a new bound method on `Parent` to `make_child()`?

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.init_args = {'args':args, 'kwargs':kwargs}
        self.children = list()
        ...  # whatever else a Parent does

    def make_child(self, child_cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if args is None:
            args = self.init_args['args']
        if kwargs is None:
            kwargs = self.init_args['kwargs']
        child = child_cls(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.children.append(child)
        return child


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parent = parent
        ...  # whatever else a Child does
```

DEMO

```
>>> p = Parent()
>>> c = p.make_child(Child)
>>> c in p.children
True
```

Comment: Thanks for the Idea. But usually I do not want my parent class to depend on the children. (For example noone else could subclass my parent, as one would need a `make_child` method for each Child class.

Comment: Aah, I understand. But then child is no more `instanceof(Parent)`, so I do not have any inheritance. I cannot call the `child.any_parentmethod()` anymore

Comment: @ProfHase85 Why not? You still have to define the child class yourself. Make it a `Child(Parent)` as before.

Comment: in your solution, the child class would not be initialized with the proper parent (as tehere is no constructor for parent in `__init__` of the child

Comment: @ProfHase85 I'm incredibly confused with what you're doing if this doesn't do everything you've asked =/

Answer (score -1):

Make your parent (and hence child)  constructor take changed a and b. You should have as little behavior in init methods as possible. Create a class method that takes unchanged a and b, changes them, and then applies the class constructor to them -- this would be good for both parent and child. Then write a static method on the child class that takes a parent object and passes its changed a and b attributes to the init method that expects changed a and b.

```
class Parent(object):
    @classmethod 
    def from_unchanged(cls, a, b):
        changed_a = change_a(a) 
        changed_b = change_b(b) 
        return cls(a, b) 

    @classmethod
    def from_parent(cls, parent):
        return cls(parentchanged_a, parentchanged_b) 

    def __init__(self, changed_a, changed_b) :
        selfchanged_a = changed_a
        selfchanged_b = changed_b
```

Comment: still the same problem: If I got 10 children, I would have to implement the method that initializes the parent on each of them. Imagine the disaster if the parent __init__ signature changes.

Comment: Oh, you meant init from the parent @ProfHase85. You can implement the child's static method as a class method and put it on a common ancestor if that's the issue. Shoot, you could even use multiple inheritance.